# signed square root SSR

Tags: matlab, matrix, normalization, sqrt

I have a matirx within n independent vectors(in which each vector is d*1 dim), now I want to do signed square root(SSR) normalization on these vectors in MATLAB, and now I have no idea what to do.
should I do sqrt on each element of each vector and then multiply it with the sign of each element?

any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define your own signed square root function.

```
ssr = @(x) sign(x).*abs(x).^(0.5)
```

Note the `.`'s to perform element wise operations.

Comment: thanks a lot, would you please tell what @(x) do?, and i want to know if function below does the same thing or not:

times(sign(x), sqrt(abs(x)))

Comment: Read https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html , if anything is unclear, comment again.